# How to select values in an array by index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

My array of todos is like this:

```
[{id:1,text:"hello"},{id:2,text:"hey"},{id:3,text:"ho"},{id:4,text:"let's go"}]
```

I am just so confused I need help with this code like this, it's for pagination in react:

```
selectTodosToDisplay = (todos, { index1: 2, index2:3 }) => {
return [...todos.slice(index1, index2), 
        ...todos.slice(index2) ]
}
```

so with the above code I want to result into this

```
[{id:3,text:"ho"},{id:4,text:"let's go"}]
```

Maybe there's other methods for this? Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#slice` returns a new array, so you don't need to spread it into a new one. The 2nd index should be 4, since `Array#slice` starts with the item in the 1st index, and ends with the item before the 2nd index. We can add 1 to the second index in the function.

```js
const todos = [{id:1,text:"hello"},{id:2,text:"hey"},{id:3,text:"ho"},{id:4,text:"let's go"}];

const selectTodosToDisplay = (todos, { index1, index2 }) => todos.slice(index1, index2 + 1);

const result = selectTodosToDisplay(todos, { index1: 2, index2: 3 });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sample = [{ id: 1, text: "hello" }, { id: 2, text: "hey" }, { id: 3, text: "ho" }, { id: 4, text: "let's go" }];
var selectedID = 1;

function filterByID(item) {

    if (item.id == selectedID) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var arry = sample.filter(filterByID)
```

I hope it's work

Answer (score 0):

Perfect use case for the [JavaScript spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const [first, second, ...rest] = [{id:1,text:"hello"},{id:2,text:"hey"},{id:3,text:"ho"},{id:4,text:"let's go"}];

console.log(rest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selectTodosToDisplay = (todos, { index1: 2, index2:3 }) => todos.slice(index1, index2 + 1)
```